# Create an image of a partition that I can mount on windows/linux

Tags: mount, disk-image

I am going to change my PC but I would like to create an image of the partition of my old PC (windows is installed there) that can I use on my new PC (I mean just reading/writing data not running the old OS).

I would like to mount this image like a new drive on my new PC (I am referring to windows) and I would like to be able to mount this image on a linux system too.

What can I use to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Use a tool that will convert your physical machine to a virtual hdd. This vhdd can then be converted and mounted using the proper software in Windows and Linux. There isn't a one size fits all format. Windows 7 and beyond supoprt mounting VHDs which is Virtual PC/Hyper-V formats. Linux would need to run vmware player or something equalivent to mount the virtual hdd there.  There are several hundred programs to create a image of your physical machine I would use the one that best fits your needs.

Comment: following on from what ramhound has said, perhaps this will do it nicely http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx  Disk2vhd by sysinternals